# Проблема с select запросом по значениям из подзапроса

Tags: sql

Уважаемые программисты, прошу помочь. Запрос:

```
select Task_name from tasks_table 
  where task_status=3 
  and task_creator=all(select id from personnel_table where chief=5)
```

в подзапросе `all(select id from personnel_table where chief=5)` несколько значений. Необходимо вывести из таблицы `tasks_table` все `Task_name` у которых `task_creator=` значениям  из `select id from personnel_table where chief=5`

Comment: А если проще, то:

как реализовать следующее:

select * from table where id=<множество чисел>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен оператор IN

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE clmn IN (1,2,3)
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE clmn IN (SELECT id FROM personnel_table WHERE chief = 5)
```

Или джойны

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
INNER JOIN personnel_table AS pt ON pt.id = tbl.clmn
WHERE pt.chief = 5
```

Что лучше с точки зрения производительности - лично я не скажу, но ходят слухи, что джойны

Comment: Благодарю, о последнем варианте я и не догадывался

Answer (score 0):

Не вполне понятно: одно значение не может быть равно множеству значений. Хотелось бы получить пример. Пока так:

```
select Task_name from tasks_table where task_status=3 and task_creator IN(select id from personnel_table where chief=5)
```

Comment: Буквально только пришел в голову такой результат. Да, он оказался верным, спасибо:)